# Full size Silverlight application dimensions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How can I set the dimensions of my root layout in the XAML to 100% width and height of the `<object>` tag that houses the Silverlight App.

I have tried specifying 100%, but the width and height properties only take unit literals (exact pixels). Is there a way I can have the Silverlight app take up all the available space in the `<object>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now (this could change in the version next of Silverlight), pretty much the only way to do this is [figure out the dimensions in JavaScript](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm) on the page, then [pass those to the Silverlight object](http://www.byteblocks.com/page/How-to-pass-objects-in-Silverlight-application-initialization-parameters.aspx).

One other option would be to use the [Silverlight/JavaScript inter-op API](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/08/tip-of-the-day-15-communicating-between-javascript-amp-silverlight.aspx)

Comment: A little less than convenient, but it'll do. Thanks!